# Is there a way of editing the odoo portal sign up page or form

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

WHen users go to sign up for their customer portal, they are greeted with a signup form that does not appear to be editable by the regular website editor. Can this form or page be edited at all?

Using Odoo9.0e enterprise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auth_signup.signup template. It is located in addons/auth_signup/views. You can modify the xml in place or inherit it in a addon of your own. Or in settings your can find the view in user interface settings and edit it in the web interface.